# Strange signal processing: is this chaos or spectral aliasing?

Tags: python, dft, aliasing

In the context of DFT calculation, I would like you to explain me why I get this red curve:

[image: Matplotlib 1]

I work with a [DFT simulator](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4603881/1107523) I built myself in Python. When I plot the output $y[t]$ with the impulsional response $h(t) = \delta (t)$, an input $u(t) = \sin(t) \nu(t)$ and with any resolution, I obtain a "normal" sinus as expected:

[image: Matplotlib 2]

As you can see, it gets tricky for $h(t) = \delta(t) + \delta(t-1)$. Here is the output for $u(t) = \nu(t)$:

[image: Matplotlib 3]

The strangest thing in it is that the signal gets stable for a lower resolution. In my example, any resolution below $100$ leads to a "normal" sinus, and above $99$ the function seems to have drunk too much whisky:

[image: Matplotlib 4]

Based on what I know, I guess it is either:

1. A **chaos** phenomenon

Or, more likely:

2. A **spectral aliasing** phenomenon

Thank you in advance for your ideas !

---

Note that I'm not a perfect coder yet and it is not impossible my program is mistaken. It seems however unlikly to me since it's only $150$ lines.

---

**Update**: here is the interesting part of my code if you want to check (the expressions of $u$ and $h$ are stored as strings, e.g. `u_expression = "d(t) + d(t-1)"` with `d(t)` $:= \delta(t)$ :

```
def draw_y(clicked):
    global drawn_y
    x = [x0 + i * resolution for i in range(samples)]

    convolution = []
    for j in range(samples):
        t = x0 + j * resolution

        new_h_expression = ""
        for char in h_expression:
            if char == 't':
                new_h_expression = new_h_expression + str(t) + "-k"
            else:
                new_h_expression = new_h_expression + char

        new_u_expression = ""
        for char in u_expression:
            if char == 't':
                new_u_expression = new_u_expression + "k"
            else:
                new_u_expression = new_u_expression + char

        conv_expression = "(" + new_u_expression + ")" + "*" + "(" + new_h_expression + ")"
        convolution.append(conv_expression)

    convolution_integration = []
    for q in convolution:
        y = []
        for j in range(samples):
            k = x[j]
            y.append(eval(q))

        int = sum(y)
        convolution_integration.append(int)
    
    axu.plot(x, convolution_integration, "-r")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: It is likely due to [Nyquist-Shannon sampling rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem), but without having a look at your code, one cannot say more.

Comment: I just added the interesting part of my code

Comment: @AlbertSchrödinberg I noticed some questions of yours with a strong coding component. They are interesting, but not fully suitable for this site. You should post on the signal processing SE or CrossValidated or the physics SE.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip. The initial purpose of this questions were not to correct my code since I suppose it is correct, but to explain some strange mathematical phenomena like this one